# How to keep the selected page on gridview after a gridview operation

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound, page-index-changed

I have a gridview with huge data, as expected pagination is there.

In the grid, i have three buttons, i.e, View, Edit,Delete

When i am clicking View, it is showing details, but whenever i am clicking back button, it **always** takes me to 1st page of grid.

How to stop that??

feel free to ask any question

thanks in advance

Comment: You need to go back with parametre on url, you read that parametre on your page load and you active and show the correct line. Need some work  here

Comment: For some certain reason, i cannot use the url. Is there any other way out??

Comment: @Arka If you can't use the url, maybe try session.  Whenever the user moves from page to page, save the current page into a session variable.  When they return to the page, check in page_load when it's not a postback, if that session value is populated use it to set them to the page you want.

Comment: Ok, I will try...@Paritosh